# How to display json data in a html modal

Tags: html, json, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I need to show json data which is in an array in a html modal. Currently the json data array is correctly shown in the console.

**javascript**

```
$('.detailButton').on('click', function(){
 var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";
 var leave_id = $(this).val();
 var i;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data:{leave_id:leave_id},
    url: BASE_URL + 'admin/AdminDashboardController/viewRequest',   

    success:function(data){                 
    console.log(data);
    $('#leave_details').html(data);       
    $('#pendingLeaveRequest').modal('show');
  },
 error:function(error){
    alert(error);
 }});
});
```

**modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="pendingLeaveRequest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-body" id="leave_details" >
            <p> </p>
          </div>
    </div>
```

**console**

[{…}]
0
:
id
:
"124"
leave_end
:
"2018-08-20"
leave_start
:
"2018-08-18"
leave_type
:
"Annual"
status
:
"0"
user_id
:
"6"
user_name
:
"Harry Potter"
**proto**
:
Object
length
:
1
**proto**
:
Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to traverse the data to display it.
Looking at your console, you can do something like this:

```
$('#leave_details').html("<p>" + data[0].id + "</p>");
```

This is just a sample, the design will be up to you.